What is the significance of the ghostly, translucent creatures—the "Buyers"?
In Hayao Miyazaki's The Boy and the Heron (2023), Kiriko and Mahito encounter several ghostly, translucent creatures while sailing to Kiriko's home. These creatures, dressed in a white shirt and straw hat, are described by Kiriko as "buyers" of the fish they caught.

The relevant scene features this dialogue:

Mahito: Who are they?
Kiriko: I guess you can call them buyers since they came here for our catch. They probably saw our flag.
They're not able to kill anything, so that's why it falls on me.

They are last seen as Kiriko and Mahito are preparing to carve the fish they caught, and they are never mentioned again.

I feel that their presence doesn’t seem essential to the narrative, which makes their inclusion all the more interesting.
What is the significance of these creatures—the "Buyers"? Could they be symbolic, or are they perhaps drawn from Japanese folklore, mythology, or other works? Is there any deeper meaning to Kiriko's flag, which seemingly attracted the buyers?


A possible idea: the main theme of the film (and its proper title) is the question How Do You Live? Here are a group of people who are helpless - they can't feed themselves. How are you going to treat them?
They also serve as a bit of a contrast to the equally hungry parakeets. See how both groups respond to their needs.
